# ROR, ruby on rails console - how to input in new line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

on Rails console. I tried to input something, I don't want input everything in one line. But when I tried to type "C-Enter" or "Shift-Enter", it doesn't work.
What should i do?

Thank you

Comment: Could you be more specific about what content is being broken across lines?  Is this a string, method definition, etc.?

Comment: i just want to Post something , and there is a long string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave a dangling line of code (ending a line with an operator or a comma)

```
puts "hello " +
  "world"

class Foo
  def this_line(is,
    unfinished)
  end
end
```

This **won't** work with MRI Ruby 1.9:

```
puts "hello
  world"
```

However, a better way of doing this would be:

```
puts <<-EOF
  hello
  world
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :010 > r.update_attributes(

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :011 >     :value=>4)
```

Use `ctrl + enter` or `shift + enter`, Both works on my rails console.

Answer (score 0):

In my rails console (i use wsl)

```
>ctrl+l -> clear console
>ctrl+j -> new line without execute intructions
```